# How to Split Column Values in DataFrames.jl (version 0.19)?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am following Mr.Tom Kwong's https://github.com/tk3369/data-wrangling-techniques-in-julia tutorial.

DataFrame as follows:

```
julia> df3=stack(df2, Not(:County), variable_name=:Year_Gender, value_name=:Suicides)
486×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Year_Gender       │ Suicides │ County       │
│     │ Symbol            │ Int64    │ String       │
├─────┼───────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Asotin       │
│ 2   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Benton       │
│ 3   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Chelan       │
│ 4   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Clallam      │
│ 5   │ Female (2012)     │ 1        │ Clark        │
│ 6   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Columbia     │
│ 7   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Cowlitz      │
│ 8   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Douglas      │
│ 9   │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Grays Harbor │
│ 10  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Island       │
│ 11  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Jefferson    │
│ 12  │ Female (2012)     │ 3        │ King         │
│ 13  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Kitsap       │
│ 14  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Lewis        │
│ 15  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Mason        │
│ 16  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Okanogan     │
│ 17  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Pacific      │
│ 18  │ Female (2012)     │ 1        │ Pierce       │
│ 19  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Skagit       │
│ 20  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Snohomish    │
│ 21  │ Female (2012)     │ 0        │ Spokane      │
⋮
│ 465 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Columbia     │
│ 466 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Cowlitz      │
│ 467 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 2        │ Douglas      │
│ 468 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 6        │ Grays Harbor │
│ 469 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 2        │ Island       │
│ 470 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Jefferson    │
│ 471 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 33       │ King         │
│ 472 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Kitsap       │
│ 473 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Lewis        │
│ 474 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Mason        │
│ 475 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 2        │ Okanogan     │
│ 476 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 3        │ Pacific      │
│ 477 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 20       │ Pierce       │
│ 478 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 3        │ Skagit       │
│ 479 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 11       │ Snohomish    │
│ 480 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 6        │ Spokane      │
│ 481 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 2        │ Stevens      │
│ 482 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 2        │ Thurston     │
│ 483 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Walla Walla  │
│ 484 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 5        │ Whatcom      │
│ 485 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 1        │ Whitman      │
│ 486 │ Total (2008-2012) │ 8        │ Yakima       │
```

I am trying to split Year_Gender column values as follows:

```
julia> df3.Year=[split(x, " ")[1] for x in df3.Year_Gender]
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching split(::Symbol, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  split(::T, ::Any; limit, keepempty) where T<:AbstractString at strings/util.jl:313
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#3#4")(::Symbol) at ./none:0
 [2] iterate at ./generator.jl:47 [inlined]
 [3] collect(::Base.Generator{Array{Symbol,1},var"#3#4"}) at ./array.jl:665
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[9]:1

julia>
```

Please guide me in splitting column values in DataFrames version 0.19, as I couldn't update.

Comment: The list of curated tutorials that are maintained to be up to date with the latest version of DataFrames.jl is given here: https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/.

Answer (score 4):

Let me start off by saying I would not recommend using DataFrames 0.19 - the current release is 1.2, so 0.19 is pretty ancient at this point. As DataFrames is past its first major release with 1.0, the API is now considered stable, so it's best to learn the current way of doing things as that will likely serve you well in the foreseeable future.

With that said, your issue has nothing do with DataFrames, and is just how base Julia works:

```
julia> split(Symbol("Female (2012)"), " ")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching split(::Symbol, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  split(::T, ::Any; limit, keepempty) where T<:AbstractString at strings/util.jl:401
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

If you want to use `split`, you need a `String` rather than a `Symbol` in your column to split it:

```
julia> split(string(Symbol("Female (2012)")), " ")
2-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 "Female"
 "(2012)"
```

You can access the second element of this using `last`, and you might want to also consider removing the brackets and then calling `parse(Int, x)` on that to get a number out.